# Execute codes after Response.End()

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

Im having trouble executing codes after Response.End().

Im using this to export a datatable/ASP Table to MS Excel(.xls).

The export finishes but my Gridview is not loading anymore. The command that I use to load the gridview is written after Response.End().

I tried using `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` but it did not help.

I tried also `Response.Redirect("Charges_Trs.aspx", false);`  still did not work..

Any help please..Here is my code

```
lblNotif.Text = "Selected items have been posted. Exporting XLS ... (will be saved in your desktop)";
exportToExcel(dt); //calls the function to export the datatable to excel, i passed dt=datatable to this function
timerNotif.Enabled = true;
btnSearch_Click(null, null); //called the event of a button that loads the gridview
```

here is the function `exporttoexcel()`

```
public void exportToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {

        Table dTable = new Table();
        TableRow dTableRow = new TableRow();

        //Column Headings
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            tCell.Text = dt.Columns[i].ToString();
            dTableRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }

        dTable.Rows.Add(dTableRow);

        //Rows
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dTableRow = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                dTableRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            }
            dTable.Rows.Add(dTableRow);
        }

        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PostedCharges" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            dTable.RenderControl(hw);
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't return 2 responses for single request...

Comment: You trying to return file and page for single response... Not going to work...

Comment: Don't get it. In what line? What am i suppose to do?

Comment: "The export finishes but my Gridview is not loading anymore. The command that I use to load the gridview is written after Response.End()." - at least to me that reads "I return file and than during the same request I render the page". Could be completely wrong - so adding comments, not an answer.

Comment: You can only return one response for each request....

Comment: Correct, after returning the file, i do something..So how can I reload the gridview, or say the page itselt if it is easier, after exporting the excel file.?

Comment: Did you mean that Response.End() and btnSearch_Click() are the responses for this one request?

Answer (score 0):

can u try adding the code in the btnSearch click event(hope it is to bind the grid with some data ) after calling export, instead of calling that click event.

Comment: I have it in my previous post..the first comment block contains the code that calls the function to export . the second block is the function that exports to excel